# How to access multiple documents from Firestore in a cloud function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is triggered on a document write. The cloud function needs to check multiple documents based on the trigger and execute if/else statements.

I've created a function that accesses all documents with a Promise.all, but this errors when trying to access all the document information  if not yet available.

```
    export function onTriggered(change, context) {
        const userPrevData = change.before.data();
        const userNewData  = change.after.data();

        const promises = [];

        // Get the uid
        const uid = context.params.userId;
        // User DocRef
        const userDoc        = firestoreInstance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
        // User Session DocRef
        const userSessionDoc = firestoreInstance.collection('sessions').doc(uid).get();
        // Solution DocRef
        const solutionDoc    = firestoreInstance.collection('solution').doc('solutionId').get();

        promises.push(userDoc, userSessionDoc, solutionDoc);

        return Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
            // Use Promise.all with snapshot.docs.map to combine+return Promise context
            return Promise.all(snapshots.map((doc) => {
                // At this point, each document and their Ids print to the console.
                console.log('docId:::', doc.id);
                console.log('docData:::', doc.data());

                const solutionDocData = getSolutionDocData(doc);
                // This will print as 'undefined' until the correct document data is processed
                console.log('solutionDocData:::', solutionDocData);
                // This will print as 'undefined' until the correct document data is processed
                const clientSeed = doc.get('clientSeed');

                // Check to see if the Users' Guess is the same as the solution
                if (userNewData.guess.color === solutionDocData.guess.color && userNewData.guess.number === userNewData.guess.number) {
                    console.log('User solution is correct');
                }

            }));

        })
    }

    function getSolutionDocData(doc) {
        if (doc.id === 'solutionId') { return doc.data(); }
    }
```

I expect 'User solution is correct' if the condition is satisfied. But, I get an error because data is undefined.

Comment: getSolutionDocData is going to return undefined any time you pass a doc to it whose id is not 'solutionId'.  There's not enough information here to understand if this is correct.

Comment: @DougStevenson as you've pointed out, and I mentioned, the information is undefined when not available. However, there was enough information in the problem. The solution was to move the logic to the .then statement, where each document is resolved and the logic can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to move most of the logic a .then()

```
    return Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
        // Use Promise.all with snapshot.docs.map to combine+return Promise context
        return Promise.all(snapshots.map((doc) => {
            // At this point, each document and their Ids print to the console.
            console.log('docId:::', doc.id);
            console.log('docData:::', doc.data());

            return doc.data();
        })).then(data => { 
        console.log('data:::', data);

        let userDocDetails = {};
        let userSessionDocDetails = {};
        let solutionDocDetails = {};

        data.forEach(document => {
            if (document.uid === uid)           { userDocDetails = document }
            if (document.serverSeedEncrypted)   { userSessionDocDetails = document }
            if (document.solutionId)            { solutionDocDetails = document }
        });


        });

    })
```

I am unsure if the data will always be returned in the order of the original promise array, so I used a forEach statement to identify unique properties and assign them accordingly.